# Z-index element isn't scrolling

Tags: css, z-index

I have an application where there's a container and inside that container a user can type a value inside an input, while he types an auto-complete box (an element with the z-index property) shows under the input and once he presses enter, the input value is saved inside a tag. A brief example of the html and css can be seen in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jefersonschimuneck/pen/dyVzVeQ) (same code below)

```css
.main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

.tag-container {
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
}

.tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 145px;
}

.auto-complete-box {
  background: #F6F2F2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class=input-container>
      <input
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="input"
      />
      <div class="auto-complete-box">
        Auto Complete Box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when my container starts to scroll (more tags added), the z-index element doesn't seem to follow it. Like in this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/jefersonschimuneck/pen/LYzjzrJ) (same code below)

```css
.main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

.tag-container {
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
}

.tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 145px;
}

.auto-complete-box {
  background: #F6F2F2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class=input-container>
      <input
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="input"
      />
      <div class="auto-complete-box">
        Auto Complete Box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want with just CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need `position: relative` on the `input-container`

Comment: Hey @RobertoZvjerković, thanks for your answer, but if I add `position: relative` to `input-container` the z-index element won't position itself above the others...

Comment: Why don’t you use `datalist`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Hey @RatajS! Thats actually a good idea! A `datalist` will work the way I want it to. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter code hereThis can not be done with `z-index`.
This requires a scrolling event in JavaScript.

```js
let tagContainer = document.querySelector('.tag-container')
let autoCompleteBox = document.querySelector('.auto-complete-box')
let input = document.querySelector('.input')

tagContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    if (e.target.scrollTop == e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight) {
        autoCompleteBox.style.top = `${tagContainer.offsetTop + tagContainer.offsetHeight - 6}` + "px";
        autoCompleteBox.style.display= "block";
    } else if (e.target.scrollTop < e.target.scrollTop < e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight) {
        autoCompleteBox.style.display= "none";
    } 
})
```

```css
.main {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

.tag-container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 600px;
}

.tag {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}

.input {
    height: 25px;
    width: 145px;
}

.auto-complete-box {
    display: none;
    background: #F6F2F2;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="tag-container">
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            <div class="tag">Tag</div>
            
            <div class=input-container>
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="input" />
                <div class="auto-complete-box">
                    Auto Complete Box
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Muhammad Ali Malekzadeh, thanks for your answer! It works the way I wanted it to work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JefersonSchimuneck - you're welcome,
I'm glad your problem was solved....
If my answer solves your problem, select the "you accept this answer" option on the left.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your absolute positioning to `position: relative;` on your `auto-complete-box`

`position: sticky;` will also work just fine.

```css
.main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

.tag-container {
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
}

.tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 145px;
}

.auto-complete-box {
  background: #F6F2F2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class="tag">Tag</div>
    <div class=input-container>
      <input
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="input"
      />
      <div class="auto-complete-box">
        Auto Complete Box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer @Kameron, but this way the z-index element stop showing above the others... =(